Custom pow function returns 0 for large exponent in C
As a beginner in C, I made my own pow function.
The type of arguments in the function and the return value are all long long int.
Here is the code:
typedef long long int lli;

lli p0wer(lli base, lli exp){
    lli p = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= exp; i++){
        p = p*base;  //we multiply exp times the base
    }
    return p;
}

The problem is for large exponent, it returns 0.
(For small values, like 10^10 it returns the result correctly)
How can I fix this?

Do you know the range of values for long long int on your platform? Would your result fall within that range?  If not, your program has undefined behavior due to signed integer overflow, and any output or other behavior is possible.

The range for long long int is 10^-18 to 10^18.

What are "large exponents"? What base did you use with those exponents? What would be the correct result for the affected numbers?

FWIW, int i = 1; i <= exp; i++ can result in an infinite loop if exp >= INT_MAX.

This is pointless to speculate about without knowing what you pass to this function and what you expect. In most contexts 10^10 is a large value.

Make sure you print it with the correct specifier: printf("42^11 is %lld\n", p0wer(42, 11)); See https://ideone.com/fnvSaL

@whoami: the range is (roughly) -10^18 .. +10^18; your lower-bound of 10^-18 is a fractional value and those can’t be stored in an integer.

2 things to mention about your code:

You're comparing i, which is an int, to exp, which is long long int. Just like @user30482 mentioned, if the exponent is larger than 2147483647 (which is maximum value of an integer), you'll have an infinite loop, as this integer will go from 1 to (INT_MAX) and then it will have an undefined behaviour.

If you're printing the result as printf("%d\n", p0wer(2, 62));, you'll always end up with 0, because the value will be larger than an integer. You should have lld specifier as @pmg mentioned.


Here's a valid code for your function:
#include <stdio.h>
typedef long long int lli;

lli p0wer(lli base, lli exp){
    lli p = 1;
    for(long long int i = 1; i <= exp; i++){
        p = p*base;  //we multiply exp times the base
    }
    return p;
}   

void main(void){
    printf("%lld\n", p0wer(2, 62));
    
}   


You can test how comparing int to long long int will result in an infinite loop:
#include <stdio.h>
typedef long long int lli;

lli p0wer(lli base, lli exp){
    lli p = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= exp; i*=2){
        p = p*base;  //we multiply exp times the base
    }   
    return p;
}   

void main(void){
    printf("%lld\n", p0wer(1, 99999999999));
    
}

This will keep running forever.
